# Python Kivy returning 'AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__''

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to build an interactive school timetable using Kivy but I keep running into problems with changing the Button text based on its name. I have created a grid layout where each button has a unique name, for example the first Button in Monday is `one_mon` the next one is `two_mon` and so on. I have created a class which inherits from `Button` and here is the Kivy and Python code for this class:

```
<Tile>:
    background_color: [.5, .9, 1, 1]
    halign: "center"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 96, 96
    text: self.lesson
    on_press: self.on_press()
    on_release: self.on_release()
```

Here is the Python code for Tile

```py
class Tile(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lesson = ""
        self.sub_press = ""
        self.check()
        self.text = self.lesson

    def check(self):
        if self.ids.one_mon == "one_mon":
            self.text = "English"
            self.sub_press = "Room nr. 42 \n Mr. Hetman"

        ...        

        else:
            self.lesson = "None"
            self.sub_press = "None"

    def on_release(self):
        self.text = self.lesson
        self.background_color = [.5, .9, 1, 1]

    def on_press(self):
        self.text = self.sub_press
        self.background_color = [.01, .9, 1, 1]
```

Here is the error message `if self.ids.one_mon.name == "one_mon": File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

Here is the code for the parent widget holding all those buttons together:

```
<PlanChart>:
    cols: 11
    padding: 2
    Tile:
        id: one_mon
        name: "one_mon"
    Tile:
        id: two_mon
        name: "two_mon"
    Tile:
        id: three_mon
        name: "three_mon"

    ......

    Tile:
        id: ten_fri
        name: "ten_fri"
```

Why am I getting this error? Is there any other way to check the id of the button? Maybe I should totaly scrap this project and start over using a diffrent tactic? Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be from the way you inherits from the **Button** Class and how you binded the proprties to the button

you should inherits from the button class and overidde the **on_release** method

after the method overiden, the word `self.text` will be reffered to as the current button inner text

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class Tile(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lesson = ""

    def on_release(self):
        self.text = self.lesson
```

Comment: I wan't it to be interactive and I'm going to use it for multiple students so the button text can't be static. For that I need that if statement, so your answer dosen't really do the job.